# Value too large for defined data type Android

Tags: android, file-upload, httpurlconnection, ioexception

I am getting a `java.io.IOException: Value too large for defined data type` when uploading a large file almost 2.1GB to a server. and My code is :

```
     URL oUrl = new URL(servierUrl);
     HttpURLConnection  connection = (HttpURLConnection) oUrl.openConnection();
       connection.setDoOutput(true);
       connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
       connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
       connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-       data");
       connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(nChunkSize));
       connection.setConnectTimeout(1800000); 

     InputStream oFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(sFilePath));

     OutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
     .
     .
     . // here I'm dividing the stream chunks, every chunk 5Mb and uploading the chuck  to server 
          but in the chunk #410 (5Mb * 410) it cause an exception return the exception as I mentioned above.
          before that every chunk I upload it success
     .
     .
```

So any help please.

Answer (score 0):

My guess-  something is using an int to hold the length of the file.  This is overflowing at 2^31-1, or about 2 billion bytes.  Looks like an issue in either the http library or the output stream.  You're going to need to either break up that file or replace the breaking component by one that works.  Which component is breaking can be found by looking higher up in the stack trace and seeing where the crash comes from.